# React Native Android app installs but won't show in app launcher

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-manifest, android-launcher

I've done a lot of research even here on SO, but I couldn't find a solution.
I've built an app using React Native and when debugging with `react-native run-android` everything works fine. Now I've exported the signed apk from android studio. When I install the app on my device, the app installs correctly, however the app doesn't show up in the launcher and I can't start the app since the "open" button is greyed.
Googling around the web I've seen that probably this is a Manifest file problem, but I almost tried everuy solution and no one worked. This is my manifest (with some values obscured due to privacy reasons)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="***.***.***">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:name="***.***.***.MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="***.***.***.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" tools:ignore="MissingClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="***" android:host="login" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="***" android:host="login" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="***" android:host="shows" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="***" android:host="shows" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong!